# Is it possible import data into text box when user select word on pdf file? (ASP.NET , VB.NET)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf

I have an ASP.NET webform (using VB.NET) which is showing a `.PDF` file. Is it possible to input data into text box when user selected a word on pdf file? We can export pdf file with the data from textbox but I have no idea about the opposite way.

I called my pdf file on my web form like that.

```
Dim embed As String = "<object data=""{0}"" type=""application/pdf"" width=""2000px"" height=""1000px"">"
embed += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = ""{0}"">here</a>"
embed += " or download <a target = ""_blank"" href = ""http://get.adobe.com/reader/"">Adobe PDF 
         Reader</a> to view the file."
embed += "</object>"
ltEmbed.Text = String.Format(embed, ResolveUrl("~/uploads/" + pdf_name))
```

Hope someone can guide me, sorry for my English.

Comment: @KJ Thz you for detail. Now I can explain what is the problem to other .

Comment: @KJ thanks again. It's really easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

No. Think about it a sec. the PDF is embedded in your webform but who is actualy serving its content is AcrobatReader not your webform